# Java Lambda to Kotlin

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

I'm building my code with Kotlin.

I've stumbled upon a problem using Lambda in Kotlin with the following:

Java code:

```
  ((UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
        .addBuilderCustomizers(builder ->
        builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true));
```

Using common interface instantiation

```
((UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
            .addBuilderCustomizers(new UndertowBuilderCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(Builder builder) {
                    builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true);
                }
            });
```

My code in Kotlin

```
val c: UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory = (container as UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory)
// Calling the Lambda
c.addBuilderCustomizers{ (b: Builder) -> b.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true) }
```

It's giving me a syntax error:

> Multiple markers at this line - Passing value as a vararg is only
>   allowed inside a parenthesized argument list - Cannot infer a type for
>   this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

What might be the correct syntax to this?

Comment: Try wrapping the lambda in parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to help Kotlin compiler a bit and tell it what is the type of this lambda. This code should compile and work just fine:

```
        c.addBuilderCustomizers(UndertowBuilderCustomizer{ it.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true)})
```